# How to fire tag between two dates?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a tag in GTM that I want to use only between two dates let's say, between 21-02-2017 20:00 and 22-02-2017 10:00. Is there any built-in way to achieve this.

I could probably make a custom variable JS that gets some date from user's browser, make sure it's utc and write a custom JS trigger that checks this date, but it seems very convoluted and error prone. Isn't there a better way to do this?

P.S. Googling for things related to GTM with the word "date" is pointless because according to google "date" = "data" and GTM just happens to use DataLayer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After replacing "date" with "utc" I did finally manage to get some results. Turns out, if I want something as simple firing a tag between two dates, I don't need to use a trigger. Instead I can set both dates in the **advanced settings** of the tag in question after I check the **Enable custom tag firing schedule** option.

However anything more complicated than that will likely require using custom JS variables and triggers. [This](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2016/09/20/fire-gtm-tags-your-schedule/) page explains how to get those more complicated cases to work (and working around user's time zone to get current time in a variable).

---

**Update:** Using JS might still be the only viable option as the built in functionality doesn't seem to work. If you enable the option, set a schedule save the tag, and then edit the tag again, the schedule will be gone and the tag will continue to fire regardless of what was entered in the **start** and **end date** fields.

The issue is described in this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/kM9WwpwYB6U;context-place=forum/tag-manager) (that no one ever bothered to respond to).

Comment: I would expect this tag firing schedule feature works as expected now, but as a note to others using it, you need to format your time in 24H format such as `15:00` or `09:00`. I tried to write things like 3PM and 9AM, but GTM gave me a generic message about my time entries being incorrect.